# Pytesseract disable dictionary (multiple configuration arguments)

Tags: python, tesseract

I have this working line of pytesseract code, which keeps only the whitelisted characters:

```
resultxt = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<").strip()
```

But now I'd like to disable the dictionary as well since my text is basically just machine text. How do I achieve this? the below doesn't change anything with `load_system_dawg` and `load_freq_dawg` to `false`

```
resultxt = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ< load_system_dawg=false load_freq_dawg=false").strip() #-psm 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> tesseract --help-extra
Usage:
  tesseract --help | --help-extra | --help-psm | --help-oem | --version
  tesseract --list-langs [--tessdata-dir PATH]
  tesseract --print-fonts-table [options...] [configfile...]
  tesseract --print-parameters [options...] [configfile...]
  tesseract imagename|imagelist|stdin outputbase|stdout [options...] [configfile...]

OCR options:
  --tessdata-dir PATH   Specify the location of tessdata path.
  --user-words PATH     Specify the location of user words file.
  --user-patterns PATH  Specify the location of user patterns file.
  --dpi VALUE           Specify DPI for input image.
  --loglevel LEVEL      Specify logging level. LEVEL can be
                        ALL, TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL or OFF.
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
  -c VAR=VALUE          Set value for config variables.
                        Multiple -c arguments are allowed.
  --psm NUM             Specify page segmentation mode.
  --oem NUM             Specify OCR Engine mode.
NOTE: These options must occur before any configfile.

Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.

OCR Engine modes:
  0    Legacy engine only.
  1    Neural nets LSTM engine only.
  2    Legacy + LSTM engines.
  3    Default, based on what is available.

Single options:
  -h, --help            Show minimal help message.
  --help-extra          Show extra help for advanced users.
  --help-psm            Show page segmentation modes.
  --help-oem            Show OCR Engine modes.
  -v, --version         Show version information.
  --list-langs          List available languages for tesseract engine.
  --print-fonts-table   Print tesseract fonts table.
  --print-parameters    Print tesseract parameters.
```

Comment: did that, but doesn't help with the python syntax

Comment: It states **Multiple -c arguments are allowed.** - you used single.